# jetpack navigation -> multiple back stack with bottom navigation not working when back stack is cleared

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-jetpack-navigation

Starting with version 2.4.0-alpha01, the NavigationUI helpers support multiple back stacks without any code change. If your app uses the setupWithNavController() methods for BottomNavigationView or NavigationView, all you need to do is to update the dependencies and multiple back stack support will be enabled by default.

In my aplication I have "Intro" screen.(TestFragment)

[image]

When user clicks on the button, app is navigating to home screen where Bottom navigation is present.

[image]

When navigating from "Intro screen" I want to clear back stack.

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/testFragment"
        android:name="com.example.android.navigationadvancedsample.TestFragment"
        android:label="Test" >

        <action
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"
            app:popUpTo="@id/testFragment"
            android:id="@+id/action_test_to_title"
            app:destination="@id/titleScreen" />
    </fragment>
```

In this situation multiple back stack funcionality is not working. There is just one back stack.
However when property popUpToInclusive is set to false multiple back stack are present and everything is working as expected!

bottom_nav.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/titleScreen"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cd_home"
        android:title="@string/title_home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/leaderboard"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_list"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cd_list"
        android:title="@string/title_list" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/register"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_feedback"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cd_form"
        android:title="@string/title_register" />
</menu>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.navigationadvancedsample.MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_container"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(
            R.id.nav_host_container
        ) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController

        // Setup the bottom navigation view with navController
        val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_nav)
        bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)

        // Setup the ActionBar with navController and 3 top level destinations
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(R.id.titleScreen, R.id.leaderboard,  R.id.register)
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    }
```

nav_graph.xml

```
<navigation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@+id/testFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/titleScreen"
        android:name="com.example.android.navigationadvancedsample.homescreen.Title"
        android:label="@string/title_home">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_title_to_about"
            app:destination="@id/aboutScreen"/>
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/aboutScreen"
        android:name="com.example.android.navigationadvancedsample.homescreen.About"
        android:label="@string/title_about" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/leaderboard"
        android:name="com.example.android.navigationadvancedsample.listscreen.Leaderboard"
        android:label="@string/title_list">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_leaderboard_to_userProfile"
            app:destination="@id/userProfile"/>
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/userProfile"
        android:name="com.example.android.navigationadvancedsample.listscreen.UserProfile"
        android:label="@string/title_detail">
        <deepLink
            android:id="@+id/deepLink"
            app:uri="www.example.com/user/{userName}"
            android:autoVerify="true"/>
        <argument
            android:name="userName"
            app:argType="string"/>
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/register"
        android:name="com.example.android.navigationadvancedsample.formscreen.Register"
        android:label="@string/title_register">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_register_to_registered"
            app:destination="@id/registered"/>
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/registered"
        android:name="com.example.android.navigationadvancedsample.formscreen.Registered"
        android:label="Registered" />


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/testFragment"
        android:name="com.example.android.navigationadvancedsample.TestFragment"
        android:label="Test" >

        <action
            app:popUpToInclusive="false"
            app:popUpTo="@id/testFragment"
            android:id="@+id/action_test_to_title"
            app:destination="@id/titleScreen" />
    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

Why multiple back stack are not supported when navigating from another fragment and clearing back stack? Maybe this is a bug in the jetpack navigation library.

Comment: bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController) remove this line and test it again

Comment: After I removed the line, bottom navigation stopped working. After clicking on items in bottom navigation nothing happens.

Comment: I dont use this method in my project, i will find a way for you

Comment: Can you use version 2.3.5?

Comment: Multiple back stacks with bottom navigation are not supported in version 2.3.5. Starting with version 2.4.0-alpha01, the NavigationUI helpers support multiple back stacks.

Comment: You should never be using an intro screen as the start destination of your graph as per the [Principles of Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#fixed_start_destination), so you should never, ever be popping the start destination off your graph in the first place. Is there a reason you are doing that at all?

Comment: User opens application for the first time.
He is navigating from "Login Screen" to "Home Screen". 
When user is in "Home screen" he should not be allowed to go back to "Login Screen".

"Login Screen" is starting destination.

Comment: Another case ->  User is navigation from "Pin Screen" to "Home Screen". When user is in "Home Screen" he should not be allowed to go back to "Pin Screen".

Comment: Neither of those cases are cases where you should be popping the start destination off your back stack - the login case is [specifically covered in the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional).

Comment: @ianhanniballake I find myself in a similar situation and while I know the fix is to not pop the start destination, I'm still curious as to why this is happening. Is this a bug in that the nav component assumes the start destination is always there and if so, is it worth enforcing this via an exception etc

Answer (score 0):

I recently walkthrough to your code and found that in your nav_graph.xml you defined testFragment as startDestination, this is the start point of your application, so when you are on welcome screen that you have bottomNavigationView, when you click on the back button, it will return to testFragment Screen, if your app is single activity (single page application)
you have to implement **OnBackPressedCallback** on the first fragment of your welcome screen, some sample code:

```
OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
@Override
public void handleOnBackPressed() {
    NavBackStackEntry backStackEntry = 
getNavController().getPreviousBackStackEntry();
    if (backStackEntry != null) {
        NavDestination destination = backStackEntry.getDestination();
        if (destination != null) {
            if (destination.getId() == R.id.homeFragment) {
                requireActivity().finish();
            }
        }
    }
    }
};
requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(callback);
```

Comment: This wont solve my problem. The fragment is still present in back stack. My goal is to remove TestFragment from back stack or just clear back stack.

Comment: You want to exit the app? Or just remove test fragment from back stack?

Comment: I want to remove fragment from back stack. If I remove TestFragment from back stack, multiple back stack funcionality stops working. This is the problem.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/navigation-multiple-back-stacks-6c67ba41952f) link, maybe it can help you

Comment: No it wont help me

Answer (score 0):

The general advice seems to be "Don't pop the startDestination" but no one really explained why.

If you look at [this comment](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-main/navigation/navigation-runtime/src/main/java/androidx/navigation/NavController.kt#565) in the NavController, you can see that it won't pop anything if it can't find the start destination in the backstack, hence your BottomNavigation Fragments end up stacking instead of popping.

> // We were passed a destinationId that doesn't exist on our back
> stack. Better to ignore the popBackStack than accidentally popping the
> entire stack

You can get around this by overriding `bottomNavigation.setOnItemSelectedListener` and implementing the navigation yourself:

```
            setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
                val options = NavOptions.Builder().apply {
                    setLaunchSingleTop(true)
                    setRestoreState(true)
                    setEnterAnim(R.animator.nav_default_enter_anim)
                    setExitAnim(R.animator.nav_default_exit_anim)
                    setPopEnterAnim(R.animator.nav_default_pop_enter_anim)
                    setPopExitAnim(R.animator.nav_default_pop_exit_anim)
                    setPopUpTo(
                        R.id.your_home_fragment,
                        inclusive = false,
                        saveState = true
                    )
                }.build()

                navController.navigate(item.itemId, null, options)
                navController.currentDestination?.hierarchy?.any { it.id == item.itemId } == true
            }
```

Where `R.id.your_home_fragment` is the id of the first navigation items Fragment.